# Continuous Everywhere

Tags: stochastic-calculus

If a stochastic process $X_{t}$ $\sim N(0,t^3/3)$ and $Y_{t}$ is defined as follows:

$Y_{t} = X_{t}/t$, if  $t>0$ and
$ Y_{t} = 0$, if $t=0$, then how can I show that $Y_{t}$ is continuous in $t>=0$ almost everywhere?

I started as follows: $X_{t}$ is continuous in $t$ and since the probability measure of $w$ such that $Y_{0}(w)=0$ is $0$, $Y_{t}$ is continuous in $t$ almost everywhere. Any help would be great.

Thanks
Trambak

**Later.** (Copied from an answer where Trambak mistakenly added it —Mariano)

Well $X_t$ is actually $\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)dW_{s}$, where $W_{s}$ is a Brownian Motion. One can show that $X_{t}$ will have a distribution as given in the question above. From this point onwards, how can I prove that $Y_{t}$ is continuous in $t$ with probability 1?

Comment: Is $X_t$ supposed to be continuous?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rewrite $\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)dW_{s}$ as $\int^t_0 W_s ds$.